# Saving process data on another table in the database

Tags: python, django, django-viewflow

I'm working on a process for my company. Doing this i have found it necesary to store data that is being inserted in the proccess. My process is working fine but instead of saving in my other model, it keeps on saving the data on the table that corresponds to the process and not my other model.

models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models
from viewflow.models import Process
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class DeliveryProcess(Process):
    #### Asignador ###
    nombre_del_entregable= models.CharField(max_length=150)
    fecha_inicio=models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, default=datetime.now)
    fecha_de_terminacion=models.DateField(auto_now=False, default=datetime.now)
    ejecutor=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='+')
    observaciones_asignador=models.TextField()

    ##### Ejecutor #####
    echa_de_ejecucion=models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, default=datetime.now)
    oberservaciones_ejecutor=models.TextField()
    finalizado= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    revisor=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='+')
    aprobacion_final= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    anadir_revisor= models.BooleanField(default=False)

    ##### Revisor #####
    #    aprobacion_final= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #    anadir_revisor= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #    nuevo_revisor= models.ForeignKey(
    #    User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,  related_name='+')
    #    obserservaciones_revisor= models.TextField()

class Revisiones(models.Model):
    id_revision= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fecha_de_revision=models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, default=datetime.now)
    revisor=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='+')
    aprobacion_final= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    anadir_revisor= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    observaciones_revisor= models.TextField()
```

flows.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from viewflow import flow
from viewflow.base import this, Flow
from viewflow.flow.views import CreateProcessView, UpdateProcessView
from viewflow.lock import select_for_update_lock
from .models import DeliveryProcess
from viewflow import frontend
from . import views

@frontend.register
class Delivery_flow(Flow):
    process_class = DeliveryProcess

    start = (
        flow.Start(
            CreateProcessView,
            fields=["nombre_del_entregable", "fecha_inicio", 'fecha_de_terminacion', 'ejecutor','observaciones_asignador']
        ).Next(this.ejecutar)
    )

    ejecutar = (
        flow.View(
            UpdateProcessView,
                fields=["fecha_de_ejecucion", "oberservaciones_ejecutor", "finalizado","revisor"],
                task_description="Ejecutar"
            ).Assign(lambda act: act.process.ejecutor
            ).Next(this.revisor_check)
    )

    revisor_check = (
        flow.View(
        views.ReView,
        fields=["aprobacion_final",'anadir_revisor',"revisor",'observaciones_revisor', 'fecha_de_revision']
        ).Assign(lambda act: act.process.revisor)
            .Next(this.split)
    )

    split =(
        #If(lambda activation: activation.process.aprobacion_final)
        flow.Switch()
        .Case(this.end, cond=(lambda act: act.process.aprobacion_final))
        .Case(this.revisor_check, cond=(lambda act: act.process.anadir_revisor))
        .Case(this.ejecutar, cond=(not(lambda act: act.process.aprobacion_finale) and (lambda act: act.process.anadir_revisor)))
    )


    end = flow.End()

    def send_hello_world_request(self, activation):
        print(activation.process.text)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from viewflow.flow.views import CreateProcessView, UpdateProcessView
from .models import Revisiones
from viewflow.decorators import flow_start_view, flow_view
from viewflow.flow.views import StartFlowMixin, FlowViewMixin

class ReView(UpdateProcessView):
    model = Revisiones
    fields = ['revisor', 'observaciones_revisor']
```

The model I'd like to save my data in is "Revisiones" and the custom view I am using is ReView but dosent save on my other table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All process views such as `CreateProcessView` or `UpdateProcessView` in Django Viewflow is connected to a **Process model**. This means that the view and the flow can keep track on meta data related to the process that gets added when you inherit from the `Process` model.

In this case, you are trying to set a `UpdateProcessView` to a `Revisiones` model that does not inherit from `Process` but is simply just a normal `models.Model`.

You are attempting to incorrectly set it by specifying `model=Revisiones` but if you open up the `UpdateProcessView` class you will see the following code:

```
@property
def model(self):
    """Process class."""
    return self.activation.flow_class.process_class
```

As you can see, the model is always set to the Process class of the Flow.

Instead what you will have to do is set the `Revisiones` data in other ways. Perhaps you create a handler in your flow that sets this data based on the Process data, or maybe you create override methods for `form_valid` or other View methods where you write custom logic to store these things.

Comment: Thanks a lot, to go around what you said I didnt' inherit Updateprocessview and instead wrote

class ReView(FlowViewMixin, generic.CreateView):